# Firestore live update using Kotlin Flow

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-flow

I want to implement system with live updates (similar to onSnapshotListener). I heard that this can be done with **Kotlin Flow**.

Thats my function **from repository**.

```
 suspend fun getList(groupId: String): Flow<List<Product>> = flow {
        val myList = mutableListOf<Product>()
        db.collection("group")
            .document(groupId)
            .collection("Objects")
            .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot: QuerySnapshot?,
                                   e: FirebaseFirestoreException? ->
                if (e != null) {}
                querySnapshot?.forEach {
                    val singleProduct = it.toObject(Product::class.java)
                    singleProduct.productId = it.id
                    myList.add(singleProduct)
                }
            }
       emit(myList)
    }
```

And my **ViewModel**

```
class ListViewModel: ViewModel() {

private val repository = FirebaseRepository()
private var _products = MutableLiveData<List<Product>>()
val products: LiveData<List<Product>> get() = _produkty


init {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main){
        repository.getList("xGRWy21hwQ7yuBGIJtnA")
            .collect { items ->
                _products.value = items
            }
    }
}
```

What do I need to change to make it work? I know data is loaded asynchronously and it doesn't currently work (the list I emit is empty).

Comment: I think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) will help understand the concept. Here is also the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firestorecleanarchitecture/data/repository/BooksRepositoryImpl.kt).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this extension function that I use in my projects:

```kotlin
fun Query.snapshotFlow(): Flow<QuerySnapshot> = callbackFlow {
    val listenerRegistration = addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
        if (error != null) {
            close()
            return@addSnapshotListener
        }
        if (value != null)
            trySend(value)
    }
    awaitClose {
        listenerRegistration.remove()
    }
}
```

It uses the [callbackFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html) builder to create a new flow instance.

Usage:

```kotlin
fun getList(groupId: String): Flow<List<Product>> {
    return db.collection("group")
        .document(groupId)
        .collection("Objects")
        .snapshotFlow()
        .map { querySnapshot ->
            querySnapshot.documents.map { it.toObject<Product>() }
         }
}
```

Note that you don't need to mark `getList` as `suspend`.

Comment: Is my view model ok? It looks like the getList function still returns empty

Comment: How do you know it's empty? Did you log `items.size` inside the `collect` block? Also, make sure that the collection and document names are correct.

Comment: Yes during debugging, the size of the list im collecting is 0. Also how can I return that flow from your example? Should I just add return statement?

Comment: Oh yes, my bad. You need to add the return keyword there. Edited the answer.

Comment: Are you sure you have data in your collection? Also, in your original code were you getting list items from the querySnapshot (inside the listener)?

Comment: Ok I have rewritten and it's working now. Thank you bro. I have one more question. How can I assign document id to the object (as I did before)?

Comment: `it.toObject<Product>()` is your object, you can store it in a variable, update its id and return it from lambda. Btw it is not recommended to use `var` properties in a data model.

Comment: So it is better to save the id as a field value when adding a product right?

Comment: You will already be getting the productId when you convert document to Product object. Why do you need to store id in a separate field. Also, maybe you can post a separate question for this providing your data model along with the question to give more context

Answer (score 9):

Starting in [firestore-ktx:24.3.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#firestore-ktx_v24-3-0), you can use the [Query.snapshots()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/ktx/package-summary#snapshots_1) Kotlin flow to get realtime updates:

```kotlin
suspend fun getList(groupId: String): Flow<List<Product>> {
    return db.collection("group")
            .document(groupId)
            .collection("Objects")
            .snapshots().map { querySnapshot -> querySnapshot.toObjects()}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2 days ago, firestore has this functionality provided out of the box: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/pull/1252/